# I can beat a polar bear in a fight

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> White and free, I roam,
> Cuttlefish, why I'd like some.
>
> Chased and hunted for what I possess,
> Why they think I'm magical is anyone's guess.
>
> I seem to like the cold, it's where I'm found.
> Clicks and whistles are my sound.

Comment: I was hoping this was the answer, because of your title :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a

> **[NARWHAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narwhal)**

Because

White and free, I roam,

> Narwhals are mostly white in colour

Cuttlefish, why I'd like some.

> Cuttlefish are eaten by whales, sharks, etc.

Chased and hunted for what I possess,

> Meat, blubber, etc, same as other whales.

Why they think I'm magical is anyone's guess.

> My unicorn horn, you know....!

I seem to like the cold, it's where I'm found.

> This is found in the Arctic regions

Clicks and whistles are my sound.

> Whales communicate with clicks and whistles.

I beat a polar bear in a fight (with thanks to @Nank)

> [Sing it with me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykwqXuMPsoc)

Comment: Not fair, your username gives you an advantage of the geography :-) Nice answer, btw.

Comment: I'd love to see an explanation of the title if you can provide it.

Comment: Thanks!  It was the "magical" "and polar" that pretty much gave it away.  You almost got there, sorry for taking many of your words - I couldn't easily find better answers to the clues.

Comment: A humourous explanation for the title: https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.22588190.0918/flat,800x800,070,f.u2.jpg

Comment: The title is explained by the fact that they are so awesome they cause commotions! (can't post a link to youtube right now but just searching "*\*answer\** song"  on the interwebs should be enough)

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I'd love to be lyrical about the magical here, but the truth is the predation goes the other way around.  Polar bears will most often kill this creature.

Comment: maybe because a narval-class submarine can easily defeat a polar bear

Comment: As suggested by @Keelhaul, and since no one has posted it yet, here it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykwqXuMPsoc . At 10s, it says "They can beat a polar bear in a fight"

Comment: @Snow - quite true - a Google search of polar bear + _answer_ gave me a lot of bears with bloody snouts standing over the carcasses of _answer_

Comment: @Keelhaul. That song is burned into my memory to such an extent that I was able to answer this riddle just from seeing the title in the HNQ list.

Answer (score 4):

You are a

> **[BELUGA WHALE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beluga_whale)**

Because

White and free, I roam,

> Beluga whales are white in colour

Cuttlefish, why I'd like some.

> Cuttlefish are eaten by whales, sharks, etc.

Chased and hunted for what I possess,

> Whale hunting is a major concern behind the dwindling whale population

Why they think I'm magical is anyone's guess.

> 

I seem to like the cold, it's where I'm found.

> This is found in the Arctic regions

Clicks and whistles are my sound.

> Whales communicate with clicks and whistles.

Comment: grrr you were faster than me ^^

Comment: This is actually not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: it fits so well though (the only problem would be the title, i'm pretty sure a polar bear would win)

Comment: Oh, well, @Kant1 maybe you can get the correct answer now :-)

Comment: @Joe-You-Know - out of curiosity, is this on roughly similar lines, or is it way off base?

Comment: You're on the right track.

Comment: I think Snow got there first, though :-)